# Dell latitude d600 USB ports

Tags: usb

I did use a communication cable which shorted out my DELL Latitude D600 usb ports.
at the time I have plugged that cable the screen went black. I did restart the computer but not one of the USB ports are working,
It's something can be fixed without replacing the motherboard?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The USB ports are built-in on the motherboard. Unless you can track and replace the chips, you have to change the whole motherboard.

As an alternative, you can purchase PCMCIA USB card for your laptop.